# go-redis Eval func return value type, when Lua script returns an array

Tags: go, redis, lua, go-redis

When a Lua script returns a table array during an Eval call, how can it be converted to a []string in go?

The redis cli returns bulk replies in the following format.

```
1) val1
2) val2
```

Will [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) eval function return the bulk entries as

```golang
["val1", "val2"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis returns Lua table arrays as RESP2 arrays. The Go client then will map that response to Go native types. The relevant documentation for `go-redis` is found here: [Lua and Go types](https://redis.uptrace.dev/guide/lua-scripting.html#lua-and-go-types).

The tl;dr is that Lua tables are indeed mapped to a bulk reply, and the Go client maps that to a slice of interface: `[]interface{}`.

Both `go-redis` script `Run` and `Eval` return a `*Cmd`. You can use methods on this type to retrieve the output as Go types. `Result` gives `(interface{}, error)`, which you can type-assert to whatever you want, otherwise, [`StringSlice`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8#Cmd.StringSlice) is a convenience getter to retrieve `[]string` right away.

So it looks like:

```golang
script := redis.NewScript(`
  local foo = {"val1", "val2"}
  return foo
`)

cmd := script.Run(/* parameters */)

i, err := cmd.Result() // (interface, error)
// or
ss, err := cmd.StringSlice() // ([]string, error)
```

If the values aren't actually all strings, use [`Slice`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8#Cmd.Slice) to get the `[]interface{}` slice, and then inspect the elements individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the encoding/json package to convert a JSON string to a slice of strings.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// jsonString is the JSON string that you want to convert to a slice of strings.
const jsonString = `["value1", "value2"]`

func main() {
   
    var stringSlice []string

    // Unmarshal the JSON string into the stringSlice variable.
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &stringSlice)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    
    fmt.Println(stringSlice) // ["value1", "value2"]
}
```

Comment: the redis cli returns bulk replies in the following format.
1) val1
2) val2
Will go-redis eval function return the bulk entry as `["val1", "val2"]`?